# Frozen Graph To Tflite Conversion Error -> ValueError - provide an input shape for input array 'wav data'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, speech-recognition, tensor

I followed the code given in the Tensorflow [github-repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands) for speech commands classification to train a custom classifier for Urban Sound Dataset. The frozen graph was created successfully. But when I tried to convert it to Tflite using [TFLiteConverter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter) as given below

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph('five_words.pb', ['wav_data'], ['labels_softmax'], {"wav_data" :None})
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

It gave the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-fc0e59056dc1> in <module>()
----> 1 tflite_model = converter.convert()
      2 open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self)
    887         if not shape:
    888           raise ValueError("Provide an input shape for input array "
--> 889                            "'{0}'.".format(_get_tensor_name(tensor)))
    890         # Note that shape_list might be empty for scalar shapes.
    891         shape_list = shape.as_list()

ValueError: Provide an input shape for input array 'wav_data'.
```

Graph Structure : 
 
[image: Graph Structure]

The data which I gave as input had **5 folders** for each word and each folder consists of **100 audio** files, so what will be the shape of my input tensor ie **'wav_data'**

Answer (score 1):

As the error trace indicates you need to provide shape of the input array 'wav_data'. You check the shape of wav_data and replace None with the array.

For example `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph('five_words.pb', ['wav_data'], ['labels_softmax'], {"wav_data" :None})` can be `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph('five_words.pb', ['wav_data'], ['labels_softmax'], {"wav_data" :[1,160,160,3]})`